# Jackson serialise property based on other property value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, java-15

I'm looking for a solution to serialize a POJO object property based on some other property value within the same POJO using Jackson.

If a property value matches some criteria then other property values should be changed as per requirement. 
For example, below is my JSON object:

```json
{
  "testProperty": "testValue",
  "object": [{
    "key": "password",
    "value": "passwordValue"
  },
  {
    "key": "key2",
    "value": "value2"
  }]
}
```

In above case, if `key`'s value matches some criteria then I should be able to change the value of `value`.

Why this is required:

- `object` is a configuration object
- And `key`-`value` are configuration settings
- In the above example one of the `key` is `password` and I need to mask/change the respective `value` of that.

One more point to add, here in this example the properties are `key` and `value`, but if we find some solution to get it applied generically to any other properties dynamically then that would be great. 
Annotating the properties can be one way but haven't found any way within Jackson to do so with custom serializers.

Thanks in advance. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check if this helps some way: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131282/skip-objects-conditionally-when-serializing-with-jackson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson has following concepts for that:

#### *Filter*: filter and control serialization of properties

**How to setup:**
The annotation `@JsonFilter` applies a *named* filter to a class (bean).
That name can be looked up in a registry to find a custom `PropertyFilter` implementation (e.g. an extension of abstract `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`).
The registry is a `FilterProvider` which can be configured with your `ObjectMapper`.

**How it works:**
So when the ObjectMapper instance is about to serialize your bean it will recognize the filter and use the logic  to a `FilterProvider`. The `FilterProvider` then controls if and how the property is serialized.

See:

- tutorial on Baeldung (2019): [Serialize Only Fields that meet a Custom Criteria with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria)
- article on CowTownCoder (2011): [Advanced filtering with Jackson, Json Filters](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html)

#### *Modifier*: modify serialization at runtime, dynamically/conditional

For example `BeanSerializerModifier` as solution to hide a field *dynamically* - based on a runtime value condition. See [Skip objects conditionally when serializing with jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131282/skip-objects-conditionally-when-serializing-with-jackson).

#### Static masking

(Probably not for your variable key/value pairs, but generally good approach for fields designed to hide sensitive data)

See [Mask json fields using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070451/mask-json-fields-using-jackson) which tries to add a specific serializer which derives its mask from a custom annotation.

Comment: thanks @hc_dev for the suggestions.
Not exactly what I was looking but it helped me solve the issue I was facing.
What I did:
Annotate the inner complex type with `@JsonFilter("myCustomFilter")` and then annotate the fields inside that complex type with custom `Mask` annotation.
This solved the issue for me to look at other property values and based on that change value of some other properties.